# Capistrano SSH Connection

Tags: php, git, ssh, capistrano, continuous-deployment

I am trying to use capistrano to deploy my php application to a server. For versionising the code, I am using GIT in combination with Bitbucket.

For CI process, I am using jenkins on a virtual machine with ip 192.168.65.68. When I develop on another virtual machine, I push changes to this machine and the CI process starts - this is working. Now I wanted to go one step ahead and use Capistrano to deploy the app (first to a new folder on the same CI machine). Within deploy.rb file of my project, I tried to connect with ssh to the project by using the same options I provide within jenkins to connect (192.168.65.68 = localhost):

```
 set :repo_url, 'ssh://git@192.168.65.68:7999/nav/myrepo.git'
 set :ssh_user, 'jenkins'
```

When I run "cap production deploy --trace", I get a connection error that the connection got blocked.

So my question is: Is my attempt to connect from the CI machine to the Bitbucket repo completely wrong? How do you connect via ssh to your repo and fetch the source code when using capistrano?